# EF call a stored procedure which has a BINARY(8) parameter, but pass an argument end with thousands of zeros

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a simple stored procedure which will return the parameter length in SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_test]
    @test BINARY(8) = NULL
AS   
    SELECT 
        CAST(DATALENGTH(@test) as BIGINT)
```

Then I generate an `.EDMX` model from this database in C# code, and call it like this:

```
using (var context = new TestEntities())
{
    byte[] testArr = new byte[8] { 0xaf, 0x29, 0x49, 0x29, 0x49, 0x29, 0x29, 0x49 }; // Just random data.
    var length = context.sp_test(testArr).First();
    Console.WriteLine(length);
}
```

It returns "8". Everything seems OK for now.

But when I opened SQL Server Profiler to trace the DB call, I saw the following:

[Thousands of zeros in parameter "@test"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7qAW.png)

I changed the parameter `@test` to `@test VARBINARY(MAX) = NULL` (without updating the `.EDMX`), and the program returns `8000`. This means the zeros were passed to the DB.

Is there someone can help explain why there are so many zeros?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @marc_s Appreciate your note and the errort to make this question clearer.

Comment: Actually, the code in ".EDMX" looks like this: <Parameter Name="test" Type="binary" Mode="In" />.  I guess because it is "BINARY"(with not length), so EF send max length of it.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing ghosts. First of all, your test does not do what you think it does. You declared your parameter as binary(8). Except for NULL values, the datalength function will always return 8 because the size is fixed.

Next is your ghost (probably). The extra zeros you see might be an artifact of profiler. Even if that value is actually passed, it does not change anything since the extras will be truncated/ignored. Changing your parameter to varbinary(max) and receiving a value of 8000 suggests that the issue is, in fact, with EF. You can chase that ghost if you want. The better question is - what are you trying to accomplish? Because your original procedure doesn't do anything useful as posted.

Comment: This test is a reproduce try for another complex program.  Thought the ghost don't change anything, it will waste the network resourse.  I doubt that all the stored procedures that have fixed length binary params will have the same issue.  I want to figure out the root cause, just for programer's curious.  Thank you for your answer.